# what happens to mysql data when computer shuts down accidentally?

Tags: mysql, database

let us say i am performing a database entry in mysql database and suddenly due to some problems my computer shuts down?Then

1.What will happen to the data that are entered?

2.If the data will be lost then is there any way I can avoid this problem?

Comment: I feel like this is better suited for [dba.SE](http://dba.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @ jnpcl what is that?how can i improve that?

Comment: @Radheshyam Nayak: Look at the questions you've asked previously, and click the Accept (green checkmark) button for the Answer that solved your problem or provided the best information.

Comment: @RadheshyamNyaka: Go back to your previous questions and accept the correct answers. If one doesn't exist, create an answer (that you found to be the solution) and mark it as such.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd wager it depends on whether you're using InnoDB or MyISAM as the engine.

MyISAM does not support transactions so it's possible you may get a partial write that leaves your data in an invalid state.

If you're using InnoDB and properly using transactions then either everything in the transaction finishes, or none of it does, so you won't get partial data (which is important if for example you're transferring money from one bank account to another, you don't want to have the case where you remove money from the first account, then power failure before it's added to the 2nd account resulting is vanishing money)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, rather than that other erroneous one.

Answer (score 2):

The point of a database software is to be the most reliable as it can be. Each action are written in a journal, everything is checked, everything is done to avoid losing data in the most extreme cases.

There's a chance your data won't be stored when the computer restart, but everything else should be fine. Concerning the last entry, it depends on when exactly did the shutdown happened.

Even with the most sophisticated safeguards, there's always a chance to lose some data. You can't achieve 100% redundancy and security.

However, to increase your chances, there's some easy things you can do :

1. plug your server on an UPS (it is like a battery which power up the computer for some time after a power failure)
2. Do regular backups
3. Avoid using the server for something else that can cause crashes

Comment: Erm...you've not even mentioned the difference in the two types of engine (InnoDB and MyISAM). MyISAM doesn't support transactions, so what you've written is wrong with respect to that engine.

Also, when you're trying to maintain the integrity of your data, a UPS really doesn't cover you. What happens when it isn't power loss that's the problem (kernel panic, or who knows what else)?

Answer (score 0):

> 1.What will happen to the data that are entered?

If it hasn't been written to disk, it's probably gone.

> 2.If the data will be lost then is there any way I can avoid this problem?

UPS (Battery backup)